# How to update margins in SharePoint list

Tags: list, css, list-form, classic-experience

I have received a very weird request from a user today. She wants no space in SharePoint list when they create a new item.

Please see below screenshot for more information:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like "margins" in SharePoint list forms.

It's all HTML & you have to hide the unnecessary HTML elements at the top by identifying their "selectors" & applying custom CSS.

like:

```
div#divId {
    display: none
}
```

Or if there is "margin" or "padding" applied to HTML elements, remove it.

like:

```
div#contentRow {
    padding-top: 0px !important
}
```

Add custom CSS using Content editor or Script editor web part on "NewForm.aspx" page.

Comment: Hi @Harris, does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.